Can I automate LinkedIn message sending with the LinkedIn API?
I'm looking for a way to automate sending custom messages to multiple LinkedIn connections using JavaScript and Node.js. Manually sending the same message repeatedly is time-consuming and inefficient. Is there a bot or script that can handle this task? I've considered using LinkedIn's API, but I'm unsure if it supports sending messages to connections.
